# Client-Server Coupling in gRPC vs REST

Tags: rest, coupling, code-contracts

Quoting [this](https://aws.amazon.com/compare/the-difference-between-grpc-and-rest/) article - `The Other key differences: gRPC vs. REST` section (client server coupling):

> Client-server coupling
>
> REST is loosely coupled, which means the client and the server do not
> need to know anything about the other's implementation. This loose
> coupling makes the API easier to evolve over time. This is because a
> change in server definitions does not necessarily require a code
> change in the client.
>
> gRPC is tightly coupled, which means the client and server must have
> access to the same proto file. Any updates to the file require updates
> in both the server and the client.

Every project that uses RESTful APIs I have worked so far - has a shared contract between client and server. For example:

**Client code (in C#):**

```
  var jsonSerializedObj = JsonConvert.Serialize(new MyRequestType { ... });
  var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(".../myPostMethod1", jsonSerializedObj);
  //response's type is part of the contract between client and server for this post method
```

**Server code (in C#):**

```
[HttpPost]
async Task<MyResponseType> MyPostMethod1(MyRequestType request)
{
   ...
   return new MyResponseType {...};
}
```

(leaving aside technical nuances/syntax errors)

1. At first, `MyRequestType` and `MyResponseType` constitute a shared contract for this specific REST api method. Meaning changing any of them impacts both client and server.
2. If contracts are serialized/deserialized as json objects and sent/returned this way - I can see how, this way, adding new object properties does not break existing versions (json deserializing will ignore properties not existent in current type) - but still, in the new version - both client and server has to know about the change in order to benefit from it.

Am I wrong ? If what I said is right/commonplace, how/where is the REST decoupling the article talks about ?

Comment: Note that a traditional website, with HTML pages with links between them, also falls within the definition of REST. It follows the definition even better than what is commonly presented as a REST API. There is definitely little coupling between the web server and the (human) consumer of the API/site.

Comment: What is confusing me is what is the minimum degree of coupling required for it to be regarded as "non existent/no coupling" between the 2 parties ? Is my point correct above in that there is, ultimately, coupling between the 2 parties involved in RESTful APIs ? If it is, and nevertheless RESTful APIs are treated as decoupled, what I describe above is NOT regarded as coupled - and what, then, will be ? gRPC, for example, shares contracts between the 2 sides of the communication, as REST does. Does the whole point revolve around the fact that gRPC shared contracts are MORE coupled than REST's ?